# CRUD Home Library Web CRUD system for recommending books to read

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing a home library project in ASP.NET Core. The principle of the application is to add books to the database by users of the application. And displaying the records in a GridView.

I want to add a functionality that will recommend other books based on the books read by the app user.
Is there an easy way to add such functionality e.g. using cookies ?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

I write applications using ASP.NET Core. The principle of the application is to add books by users to the CRUD database operations.

Comment: Post what you have tried, where you are stuck or any errors you get getting. Someone will be very happy to help.